# Monospaced fonts with small capitals

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, free, monospace

I'm currently working on a project. I'm looking for free monospaced fonts that have built-in small capitals. So far I have found only the following: `Fragment Mono`, `Roboto Mono`, `Noto Sans Mono`, and `Julia Mono`. The first three are available on Google Fonts, the last on GitHub. My favorite monospaced font `Source Code Pro` unfortunately lacks small caps and the designers said on their GitHub that they don't intend to add them. :(

EDIT: I have also found `Latin Modern Mono`.

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

- [Orator](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/orator-std?refby=pixilate)
- [JetJane Mono Caps](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/ingrimayne-type/jetjanemono)
- [Martha](https://coppersandbrasses.com/typefaces/martha/)
- [TheSans Mono](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/the-sans-mono-font-lucasfonts?tab=glyphs&refby=pixilate)
- [Novel Mono](http://www.atlasfonts.com/typefaces/novel-mono/)
- [Marfa Mono](https://abcdinamo.com/typefaces/marfa)
- [Lekton](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lekton)
- [Cousine](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/cousine)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just checked Cousine on Google Fonts. It doesn't appear to have small caps.

Comment: I downloaded it, and it does have them: https://share.cleanshot.com/cRKzX8PF